# How to show Nautilus toolbar and file tree sidebar?

Tags: nautilus

I've installed the latest Scientific Linux 6. But when I opened the included Nautilus file manager, there is no file tree sidebar and no toolbar, nor status bar. How do I activate them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the sidepane, you can either hit `F9` or go to `View` and select `sidepane`.

Similarly, for the toolbar and status bars, select them from the `View` menu.

Comment: Hitting F9 didn't work, and I don't see those options in my View menu! What's wrong? BTW, I am using Nautilus version 2.28.4.

Comment: I'm on 2.32.0. You are in spatial mode http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/stable/nautilus-presentation.html.en Open run menu (Alt-F2) enter gconf-editor and browse to apps/nautilus/preferences and select "always use browser."

Answer (score 3):

There's another option:

If Nautilus (your file manager) is just a box (spatial view) go to "edit", then select "preferences" and in "behaviour" choose "Always open in browser windows".
Then close the window and open it again.

Comment: And if that option doesn't show up then see my answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434155/how-to-launch-browser-mode-by-default-in-older-versions-of-nautilus/434157#434157