# How to launch browser mode by default in older versions of Nautilus

Tags: rhel, nautilus, settings, file-browser

Older versions of **nautilus** (such as on Red Hat 5 / RHEL 5) don't have the option **"Always use browser"** under `edit->preferences->behavior`. That option isn't added to the gui-based preferences menu until later.

This leaves you stuck only launching visual mode windows by double-clicking. This is annoying when you want to open the browser window but forget to do the extra step of right clicking and selecting **"Browse Folder"**.

How can you configure **nautilus** to launch browser mode on double click if the **"Always use browser"** option isn't appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available through the GUI on the nautilus version that ships with RHEL 5 but can still be set using the command line. You'll need to use [gconftool-2](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gconftool-2/) which is available on RHEL 5. This is the command:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_browser true
```